# Understanding why ALL_nfa is in co-nspace

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity, nondeterminism

I'm trying to understand Sipser's example showing that $ALL_{nfa} \in Co-NSPACE(n)$, where $$ALL_{nfa} = \{ <A> | A \text{ is an NFA such that } L(A) = \Sigma^*\}.$$

The algorithm can be seen [here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=X0puCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA336&ots=oWGVPz4jbZ&dq=all_nfa%20co-nspace&pg=PA333#v=onepage&q=all_nfa%20co-nspace&f=false).

I'm confused by a few things, but mainly what is meant by "nondeterministically select an input symbol"? If I "nondeterministically" choose symbol 'a' and then mark all the vertices I can reach from the current ones by 'a', then don't I possibly miss out on the vertices reachable by 'b'? And even though we repeat this $2^q$ times, what's to stop me from choosing that 'a' transition each time?

If my instincts are correct, then what we are trying to do is convert the nfa to a dfa (which will have at most $2^q$ states). If the dfa has a single reject state, then we know the nfa has a string that will be rejected. However, we would like to do this without actually converting to a dfa, which might require too much space. So the provided algorithm tries to traverse the corresponding dfa graph, without actually building it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To show that $ALL_{\mathsf{NFA}}$ is in $\mathrm{co-NSPACE}(n)$, we must show that the complement $\overline{ALL_{\mathsf{NFA}}}$ is in $\mathrm{NSPACE}(n)$.

The complement is

$$\overline{ALL_{\mathsf{NFA}}} = \{ \langle N \rangle \mid N \text{ is an NFA where } L(N) \neq \Sigma^* \}$$

To show that $\overline{ALL_{\mathsf{NFA}}}$ is in $\mathrm{NSPACE}(n)$ we therefore need to devise a Turing machine that, given an NFA description $\langle N \rangle$ can tell us if there exists an input that $N$ will not accept.

Essentially, the machine will nondeterministically guess a string $w$ and verify that this string is not accepted by $N$.  Our machine may guess the wrong string, but remember that the machine is *nondeterministic* -- as long as *it is possible to* guess a string with this property, the machine will accept $\langle N \rangle$.

To guess such a string $w$ and check that the NFA does *not* accept it, we need to explore *all* the possible computations of $N$ on $w$ and show that none of them will lead to an accepting state. This does *not* require us to construct an equivalent DFA using the subset construction; doing this would require more than linear space. However, even just storing all of the computations of $N$ on $w$ on the Turing machine tape will require more than $n$ tape cells.

The trick is to guess the string symbol by symbol and keep track of the sets of states that $N$ could possibly be in after it has read a symbol. If $N$ has $q$ states, there are $2^q$ such sets of possible states. We start with the set $\{ q_0 \}$ and guess a sequence of $2^q$ symbols. For each symbol that we guess, we record the subset of states that can be visited from any of the states that $N$ could be in now. We can keep track of this subset of possible current states using $q$ bits (represented as $q$ cells on the tape). This is linear in $n$ where $n$ is the length of $\langle N \rangle$. This description must at the very least list the states of $N$, so $q = O(n)$.

If the set of possible current states that we are now in does  not contain an accept state, then we have found a string that cannot be accepted by $N$. We may have to guess $2^q$ symbols, since each symbol could in principle lead us to a new set of possible current states that had not been seen before. But once all sets of possible current states have been examined, we can stop. We can count to $2^q$ in binary using no more than $q$ bits. Again this requires no more than $O(n)$ bits.

Comment: Nice explanation! Perhaps it's also worth briefly mentioning why the NFA state transitions cannot be guessed and have to be all simulated, as this is a usual point of confusion with this proof.

Comment: See the part of my answer that begins with "To guess such a string..."

Comment: Yes I am not saying you did not mention that all paths need to be checked. I am saying that a confused reader might wonder *why* not use non-determinism to check a single path. Not pointing errors in your answer, just suggesting an improvement :).

Comment: I'm still missing a main point somewhere... I understand that we can check all the possible computations of $N$ on $w$ by doing a sort of breadth first search using $w$ as our guide. What I'm still blocking on is the "nondeterministic guess" of $w$. If we guess the string "aaabbb....." and check all possible computations on it, couldn't we miss out on the results of trying something like "bbbaaa....?

Comment: @theQman. To make life simple, let's say the alphabet is $\{a,b\}$. Then our machine will guess that the first symbol of $w$ is $a$ and (in another universe, if you like) will also guess that the first symbol is $b$. Continue this "cloning of universes" for the second symbol, the third, and so on. That's how nondeterminism works: if there's any universe in which $N$ doesn't accept its particular version of the input, we've found what we needed.

Comment: Ahh, I think I found the source of my confusion: there are actually two levels of non-determinism going on here? There is the non-deterministic Turing machine that we get to construct, and then there is the NFA which we are given as input? So we non-deterministically run the non-deterministic automaton?

Comment: The only nondeterminism in the construction is that of guessing symbols. The simulation of each step by the NFA is entirely deterministic with no guessing involved, since one records the set of all possible successor states.

Comment: @Hans Hüttel I see. One last question to make things crystal clear: when running an nfa we can imagine branching on symbols that are the same, so when we read an 'a' we transition to all possible new states that can be reached via 'a', in parallel. But in the simulation of the Turing machine $N$ above, we seem to be branching on all possible *different* symbols so as to try out all $2^q$ strings in parallel. How can I better imagine this non-deterministic Turing machine as an nfa that branches on the *same* symbols?

Comment: No, the simulation does not "branch on all possible different symbols". If we guess an $a$ and know that we could be in any of the states $q_1, \ldots, q_k$, we must then find the set of states that can be reached from any one of these – that is, the set $$R_1 = \bigcup_{q \in \{q_1, \ldots,q_k \}} \delta(q,a)$$ where $\delta$ is the transition function of the NFA. When we guess the next symbol in what is to be a non-accepted string, we then start from $R_1$ and find $$R_2 = \bigcup_{q \in R_1} \delta(q,a')$$ where $a'$ is the symbol that we have now nondeterministically guessed.

Comment: We are only interested in finding out if we can reach an accepting state of the NFA.

Comment: I understand almost all of what you're saying, but still don't see why you say 'No, the simulation does not "branch on all possible different symbols". ' Maybe I should have said $N$ instead of "simulation". Don't we view our Turning machine $N$ as branching on all possible symbols, and therefore eventually trying all strings of length $2^q$? Isn't this what is meant by "nondeterministically guessing"?

Comment: One can think of nondeterminism as unbounded parallelism – that when a nondeterministic choice is made, all possible choices are carried out in parallel. However, in my experience this "branch on all choices" is often leads to confusion when we are supposed to carry out a complexity analysis. Students often seem to think that the nondeterministic machine must somehow use resources for every possible nondeterministic choice. It does not. It is better to think of nondeterminism as an algorithm guided by coin tosses or by the roll of a die.